# Get error in browser console when usimg python server

Tags: javascript

I get this error while running an html file which contains a form. It is supposed to move to another screen after login.

```
GET http://mdsad.com/p.js?v=1373144857354
```

I cannot understand where I am going wrong in the code. It doesn't even enter the function that is called.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/stackmob-js-0.9.1-bundled-min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Pocket Docket</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function nextpage() {
    alert("function");
    StackMob.init({
        publicKey: "my_key",
        apiVersion: 0
    });
    var u = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var p = document.getElementById('password').value;
    alert(u);
    alert(p);
    var user = new StackMob.User({
        username: u,
        password: p
    });
    user.login(false, {
        success: function(model, result, options) {
            alert("Success");
            alert("Success");
            window.open('newp1.html');
            StackMob.isUserLoggedIn(u, {
                yes: function() {
                    alert("Logged In!");
                },
                no: function() {
                    alert("Login Error!");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(model, result, options) {
            console.log(result);
            alert("Login Error!");
        }
    });
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topPan">
    <div id="topHeaderPan"></div>
    <div id="toprightPan"></div>
</div>
<div id="bodyPan">
    <div id="bodyleftPan">
        <h2>Pocket Docket</h2>

        <p class="greentext">For Every Salesman</p>

        <p>Pocket Docket is a means to simplify the working of the sales
        department in a company.</p>

        <p>For every salesperson, it is like a manager, assigning tasks and
        recording progress, updating it on their profiles. Easier to manage,
        higher the productivity.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyrightPan">
        <div id="loginPan">
            <h2>Pocket Docket <span>login</span></h2>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <label>Login ID</label><input id="email" name="email" type=
                "text"> <label>Password</label><input id="pass" name="pass"
                type="password"> <input class="button" name="Input" onclick=
                "nextpage()" type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
            <ul>
                <li class="nonregister">Forgot Password &nbsp;?</li>

                <li class="register">
                    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="loginBottomPan">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is in download.js (some file i don't know in the browser console).
Please tell me where is the error.

Comment: you defined the function `nextpage()` but where exactly should that function be used??

Comment: @Ahmed Ali: its a typing mistake. i added an onclick on the button- login.

Comment: in that case it is working.

Comment: check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EEvUb/)

Comment: the function is working alright. but i get a login error everytime. i dont think the login request even reaches the stackmob server. im running it on stackmob's python server. and it gives that error i mentioned in the question.

Comment: do you mind checking your JS file,because from the error message i can say there's a .js file that error.

Comment: but there is no download.js file in my folder :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what was wrong with your code:

```
var u = document.getElementById('username').value;
var p = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

where your input Id's are 'email' and 'pass'
so change the above lines to :

```
var u = document.getElementById('email').value;
var p = document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

also 
    
it's better to close "input" markup
    
Hope it works now.

Comment: oh yes! that was a mistake! plus i also used the submit type instead of button type. Anyway, it worked. Thanks :)